# Python - Send Function Into Text Document

Tags: python, text

Using Python version 2.x , I'm trying to put the contents of a function into a text document. Can someone please push me in the right direction of where to look. My code at the moment looks like this:

```
def Main():
    Class_AInput = int(raw_input('Enter Class A tickets sold: '))
    total_profit(Class_A_Input)

def total_profit(Class_A_Tickets):
    print (Class_A_Ticktes * 15)
    text_file = open('test.txt', 'w')
    text_file.write('Output: %s' % total_profit)
    text_file.close()

Main()
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: I'm assuming this must be some sort of homework problem.

Comment: @woo, are you getting an error? Is that not working? What's the problem? What's expected and actual output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've edit your syntax. I think you need to convert int to string first

```
def Main():
    Class_A_Input = int(raw_input('Enter Class A tickets sold: '))
    total_profit(Class_A_Input)

def total_profit(Class_A_Tickets):
    print (Class_A_Tickets * 15)
    a = Class_A_Tickets * 15
    b = str(a)
    text_file = open('test.txt', 'w')
    text_file.write(b)
    text_file.close()

Main()
```

Comment: please use correct spelling, and don't shorten words like "you" to "u". I've edited your answer.

Comment: Awesome. Thanks very much for that. I'm new to functions, just got my mind into variables, then they move the bar :)

Comment: @josh smeaton : thanks very much for correcting my spelling. My english is not well..hehe :D but Thanks

Answer (score 0):

So it's hard to know exactly where to start.  You have several typos in the code that you typed into your question (including mis-spellings of your variable and parameter names) and you're writing a reference to a function into your output file rather than writing any sort of result.

In addition your same code doesn't follow the common conventions of Python coding.

Here's a rather rough, but working, version of what you seem to be trying to do:

```
 #!/usr/bin/env python

 def Main():
     Class_A_Input = raw_input('Enter Class A tickets sold: ')
     try:
         Class_A_Input = int(Class_A_Input)

     except ValueError, e:
         print "Unable to parse int(%s): %s" % (Class_A_Input, e)

     else:
         total_profit(Class_A_Input)

 def total_profit(Class_A_Tickets):
     result = Class_A_Tickets * 15
     print result
     text_file = open('test.txt', 'w')
    text_file.write('Output: %s\n' % result)
    text_file.close()

 if __name__ == '__main__':
     Main()
```

Notice some of the differences:

- including a #! line which is conventional and will allow this code to run on UNIX/Linux/MacOS X systems.  (It'll be treated as a comment on on other systems).
- fixed the obvious typos (variable and parameter names)
- separated the `raw_input` from the attempt to parse that into an integer and wrapped that attempt in a simple exception handling block
- separated the calculation from the `print` and bound it to a local name ("assigned it to a local variable" in the more common programming parlance; there are technical nuances which distinguish name binding from variable assignment, but those are way beyond the level of discussion at hand)
- changed the `.write()` call to interpolate the resulting value into its output rather than a reference to the enclosing function
- added the `if __name__ == '__main__':` and indent the call to `Main()` into its suite according to the prevailing Python custom

Overall this will work and it somewhat more like a Python script should look.  However, it's still ugly.

Answer (score 0):

There were some problem with you text editor I think, did you use UNICODE editor sometimes while editing the file? What test editor did you use?

There was also an undeclared variable too... here is a working version of it...

```
def Main():
    Class_A_Input = int(raw_input('Enter Class A tickets sold: '))
    total_profit(Class_A_Input)

def total_profit(Class_A_Tickets):
    print Class_A_Tickets * 15
    total_profit = Class_A_Tickets * 15
    text_file = open('test.txt', 'w')
    text_file.write('Output: %i' % total_profit)
    text_file.close()

Main()
```

Just an advice from a fellow novice, :) Try not to use this type or code structure in Python. The language is made to make programming simpler...